# Matrix of the form $E_{ij}$ where $i$ and $j$ are positive integers

Tags: notation

I am trying to solve Problem 15 on page 107 of Brešar's [*Uvod v Algebro*](https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~bresar/documents/UvodVAlgebro2018.pdf).  The question translates into English as:

> Explain why any endomorphism of the algebra $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ can't map the matrix $E_{11}$ to the matrix $E_{12}$.

In this question, what does the notation $E_{ij}$ mean?

Comment: Maybe it could refer to the matrix that has a $1$ in row $i$, column $j$ and zero in everything else.

Comment: $$E_{ij} = \begin{pmatrix} e_{11} & e_{12} & \dotsb & e_{1n} \\ e_{21} & e_{22} & \dotsb & e_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots && \vdots \\ e_{n1} & e_{n2} & \dotsb & e_{nn} \end{pmatrix}, $$ where each $e_{ij}$ is a number.  Possibly.  It would be helpful to know what book you are reading out of.

Comment: It's not in English so I doubt that would help. I'm gonna write out the problem in my question for (hopefully) more clarity.

Comment: There are people here who speak languages other than English.  Moreover, it is often possible to parse the mathematics without actually being able to read the surrounding text.  Knowing what book you are using is, frankly, *vital* context, since the notation you are using is not universal.  That being said, the context you added suggests that @Azif00's comment may be correct.

Comment: $$E_{11}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad E_{12}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad$$

Comment: If $e_k$ is the vector of zeros with one in the $k$th position, then $E_{ij} = e_i e_j^T$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson It's Brešar's Uvod v algebro

Comment: See page 35 of your book.

Comment: Thanks, Azif, it's all there. And for anyone else wondering, Azif's first comment is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The notation is explained at the top of page 35 of [the same text](https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~bresar/documents/UvodVAlgebro2018.pdf).  In this text, $E_{ij} \in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ is the *standard basis matrix* with a $1$ in the $j$-th column of the $i$-th row, and $0$s everywhere else.  There are four such matrices:
$$
E_{11} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\quad
E_{12} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\quad
E_{21} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\quad\text{and}\quad
E_{22} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
In (linear) algebra and analysis, it is common to use the notation $e_i$ (or $e^{(i)}$) to denote the $i$-th standard basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  That is, $e_i$ is a vector of length $n$ with a $1$ in the $i$-th position and $0$s everywhere else, i.e.
$$
e_1 = (1, 0, \dotsc, 0),\qquad
e_2 = (0, 1, \dotsc, 0),\qquad\dotsc,\qquad
e_n = (0, 0, \dotsc, 1).
$$
Every vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as a linear combination of these vectors, so they give us a natural way of decomposing general vectors into simpler objects.  Similarly, every matrix in $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ may be written as a linear combination of the $E_{ij}$s, hence the author's adoption of this notation—using a capital $E$ to distinguish matrices from vectors—is reasonable and not entirely unheard of.

It may also be worth noting, as per copper.hat's comment, that
$$
E_{ij} = e_{i}^\intercal e_{j},
$$
where $e_{i}^\intercal$, a column vector, is thought of as an $m\times 1$ matrix; and $e_{j}$, a row vector, is thought of as a $1\times n$ matrix.